# ag-Grid for Angular: supported Angular versions

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to find out what is the latest version of ag-Grid that supports Angular 5.
I've searched for requirements in "Getting Started" guides (for current and older versions) and Readme repository files, but I didn't succeed. Where can I found it?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it is not coupled, as long as you're using Angular 2+, you can use any version of `Ag-Grid`.

However, Angular 5 was released November 2017 and you can go through this and find the version that was released around then to get the version.

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-angular/releases

I would go with `15.0.0` for the exact date. But like I said, Ag-Grid requires Angular 2+ so I would go with latest version of Ag-Grid.